# Xcode - ipa application installs on iphone but not on ipod touch

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipod, ipa

I have 2 devices:

Model: iPod touch
Localized Model: iPod touch
Firmware Version: 6.1.3
Multitasking Supported: Yes
Capacity (Disk Space): 13.75 GB
Available (Free Space): 13.53 GB
System Name: iPhone OS
Date: 15 June 2013

and

Device Information:
Model: iPhone
Localized Model: iPhone
Firmware Version: 6.1.3
Multitasking Supported: Yes
Capacity (Disk Space): 13.57 GB
Available (Free Space): 13.22 GB
System Name: iPhone OS
Date: 10 June 2013

I am member of iOS development team, and did install provisioning profile with this devices selected. The problem is: my app works fine on iPhone but when my client tries to sync app to his ipod touch it says: "Failed to install application". Please advice.

Comment: Your client's device doesn't have the provisioning profile.

Comment: May be in your info.plist parameter "Required device capabilities" is only armv7 but iPd touch don't compatibility that? Try add armv6.

Comment: My client forgot to sync the provisioning profile to his iPod. @H2CO3 was correct.

Answer (score 0):

To install the application on the device you should have provisional profile which has UUID of the target device.

The provisional profile which you are having right now contains UUID of both your devices. You should also add the UUID of your client's device as well in order to install on it.